# Android 12 cellbroadcastreceiver permission denial causing high CPU usage in com.android.phone process?

Tags: performance, bugs, android-12

Every since my Nokia 5.3 was upgraded to Andoid 12 recently, the battery suffers from processes com.android.phone and qcrild using the CPU a fair amount.  It is not completely reproducible, but it happens especially when the the phone is locked, or at least the screen is off.

I observe that increased CPU usage via `adb shell top -u radio`.

At that same time `adb shell dumpsys phone` shows a lot of the following:

```
❯ adb shell dumpsys phone
------- PhoneGlobals -------
  mPrevRoamingNotification=0
  mDefaultDataSubId=1
  mDataRoamingNotifLog:
  isSmsCapable=true
    2022-11-23T13:56:23.510818 - dataAllowed=true, reasons=Data allowed reason: NORMAL
    2022-11-23T13:56:23.512116 - dataAllowed=true, reasons=Data allowed reason: NORMAL
[snip rest of the output]
```

And that seems to always immediately follow these `adb shell logcat -d phone` warnings about `...without a qualified user` and `Permission Denial` to read the phone state:

```
11-23 13:56:23.460  1681  3481 W ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcastMultiplePermissions:1206 com.android.server.TelephonyRegistry.broadcastServiceStateChanged:2880 com.android.server.TelephonyRegistry.notifyServiceStateForPhoneId:1608 com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephonyRegistry$Stub.onTransact:455 android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal:1184
11-23 13:56:23.461  1681  3481 W ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcastMultiplePermissions:1256 android.content.Context.sendBroadcastMultiplePermissions:2215 com.android.server.TelephonyRegistry.broadcastServiceStateChanged:2884 com.android.server.TelephonyRegistry.notifyServiceStateForPhoneId:1608 com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephonyRegistry$Stub.onTransact:455 
11-23 13:56:23.462  1681  3481 W ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcastMultiplePermissions:1256 android.content.Context.sendBroadcastMultiplePermissions:2215 com.android.server.TelephonyRegistry.broadcastServiceStateChanged:2891 com.android.server.TelephonyRegistry.notifyServiceStateForPhoneId:1608 com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephonyRegistry$Stub.onTransact:455 
11-23 13:56:23.463  1681  2031 W BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE flg=0x1000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.cellbroadcastreceiver/com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver.CellBroadcastReceiver requires android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE due to sender android (uid 1001)
11-23 13:56:23.463  1681  2031 W BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE flg=0x1000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.cellbroadcastreceiver/com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver.CellBroadcastReceiver requires android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION due to sender android (uid 1001)
11-23 13:56:23.464  1681  3481 W ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcastMultiplePermissions:1256 android.content.Context.sendBroadcastMultiplePermissions:2215 com.android.server.TelephonyRegistry.broadcastServiceStateChanged:2895 com.android.server.TelephonyRegistry.notifyServiceStateForPhoneId:1608 com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephonyRegistry$Stub.onTransact:455 
11-23 13:56:23.465  1681  2031 W BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE flg=0x1000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.cellbroadcastreceiver/com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver.CellBroadcastReceiver requires android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE due to sender android (uid 1001)
```

And that results in a lot of logging that seems to be about refreshing the data about my mobile carrier (`onRefreshCarrierInfo()`), which may be where the CPU time is actually spent (following log capture is from a later occurrence):

```
11-23 14:18:08.592  2936  2936 D ServiceStateProvider: subId=1
11-23 14:18:08.592  2462  2640 I CustomizedNetworkIcon: getConfigValueByKey: oem_key_rat_name_of_4g_int=0
11-23 14:18:08.595  2462  2640 I CustomizedNetworkIcon: getConfigValueByKey: oem_display_lte_icon_int=1
11-23 14:18:08.597  2936  2936 I Telephony: TelecomAccountRegistry: onSubscriptionsChanged - reregister accounts
11-23 14:18:08.598  1676  2040 D CompatibilityInfo: mCompatibilityFlags - 0
11-23 14:18:08.598  2936  2936 D Telephony: isEmergencyPreferredAccount: subId=1, activeData=1
11-23 14:18:08.598  1676  2040 D CompatibilityInfo: applicationDensity - 280
11-23 14:18:08.598  2936  2936 D Telephony: isEmergencyPreferredAccount: Device does not require preference.
11-23 14:18:08.598  1676  2040 D CompatibilityInfo: applicationScale - 1.0
11-23 14:18:08.600 31066 31066 D CellBroadcastReceiver: onReceive Intent { act=android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE flg=0x1000010 cmp=com.google.android.cellbroadcastreceiver/com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver.CellBroadcastReceiver (has extras) }
11-23 14:18:08.600 31066 31066 D CellBroadcastReceiver: onServiceStateChanged, ss: 0
11-23 14:18:08.600 31066 31066 D CellBroadcastReceiver: networkOperator: 20416
11-23 14:18:08.600 31066 31066 D CellBroadcastReceiver: update supported roaming operator as
11-23 14:18:08.601  2936  2936 I Telephony: isRttCurrentlySupported -- regular acct, hasVoiceAvailability: false
11-23 14:18:08.601  2936  2936 I Telephony:  isRttSupported: false
11-23 14:18:08.601  2936  2936 I Telephony:  isUserRttSettingOn: false
11-23 14:18:08.601  2936  2936 I Telephony:  alwaysAllowWhileRoaming: false
11-23 14:18:08.601  2936  2936 I Telephony:  isRoaming: false
11-23 14:18:08.601  2936  2936 I Telephony:  isOnWfc: false
11-23 14:18:08.607  2462  2640 E CustomizedImsIcon: customizedVoLTEandVoWiFiIcon:
11-23 14:18:08.608  2462  4440 I CustomizedImsIcon: [0] customizedImsIcon:++
11-23 14:18:08.608  2462  4440 D CustomizedImsIcon: isAirplaneModeOn: false
11-23 14:18:08.608  2462  4440 D CustomizedImsIcon: customizedImsIcon:clear all vowifi icon which is added with TAG when airplane is off
11-23 14:18:08.608  2462  4440 I CustomizedImsIcon: [0] isOperaterCustomized:mccmnc=20416
11-23 14:18:08.609  2462  4440 I CustomizedImsIcon: [0] isOperaterClaroCustomized:mccmnc=20416
11-23 14:18:08.609  2462  4440 I CustomizedImsIcon: [0] isCustomizedBySkuId:isCustomized=false
11-23 14:18:08.609  2462  4440 D CustomizedImsIcon: getSimCount: simCount=1
11-23 14:18:08.610  2462  4440 I CustomizedImsIcon: [0] isWifiCallingAvailable: isImsRegistered is false
11-23 14:18:08.610  2462  4440 I CustomizedImsIcon: [0] isShowVoWiFiIcon: isAllowed=false
11-23 14:18:08.612  2462  4440 I CustomizedImsIcon: [0] isAllowShowVoLteIcon:OEM_ALLOW_SHOW_VOLTE_ICON_BOOL=false  phoneId=0
11-23 14:18:08.612  2462  4440 I CustomizedImsIcon: [0] isShowVolteIcon: isAllowed=false
11-23 14:18:08.613  2462  4440 I CustomizedImsIcon: [0] customizedImsIcon:--
11-23 14:18:08.615  2936  2936 I Telephony: reRegisterPstnPhoneAccount: subId: 1 - no change
11-23 14:18:08.615  2936  2936 D CallNotifier: updatePhoneStateListeners: update CF notifications.
11-23 14:18:08.616  2936  2936 I NotificationMgr: updateCfi: subId= 1, visible=N
11-23 14:18:08.616  2936  2936 I NotificationMgr: updateMwi(): subId 1 update to false
11-23 14:18:08.618  2462  2462 D KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE
11-23 14:18:08.618  2462  2462 V KeyguardUpdateMonitor: action android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE serviceState={mVoiceRegState=0(IN_SERVICE), mDataRegState=0(IN_SERVICE), mChannelNumber=1656, duplexMode()=1, mCellBandwidths=[], mOperatorAlphaLong=Simpel, mOperatorAlphaShort=Simpel, isManualNetworkSelection=false(automatic), getRilVoiceRadioTechnology=14(LTE), getRilDataRadioTechnology=14(LTE), mCssIndicator=unsupported, mNetworkId=-1, mSystemId=-1, mCdmaRoamingIndicator=-1, mCdmaDefaultRoamingIndicator=-1, mIsEmergencyOnly=false, isUsingCarrierAggregation=false, mArfcnRsrpBoost=0, mNetworkRegistrationInfos=[NetworkRegistrationInfo{ domain=CS transportType=WWAN registrationState=HOME roamingType=NOT_ROAMING accessNetworkTechnology=LTE rejectCause=0 emergencyEnabled=false availableServices=[VOICE,SMS,VIDEO] cellIdentity=CellIdentityLte:{ mCi=70817281 mPci=66 mTac=527 mEarfcn=1656 mBands=[] mBandwidth=2147483647 mMcc=204 mMnc=16 mAlphaLong=Simpel mAlphaShort=Simpel mAdditionalPlmns={} mCsgInfo=null} voiceSpecificInfo=VoiceSpecificRegistrationInfo { mCssSupported=false mRoamingIndicator=1 mSystemIsInPrl=-1 mDefaultRoamingIndicator=-1} dataSpecificInfo=null nrState=**** rRplmn=20416 isUsingCarrierAggregation=false}, NetworkRegistrationInfo{ domain=PS transportType=WWAN registrationState=HOME roamingType=NOT_ROAMING accessNetworkTechnology=LTE rejectCause=0 emergencyEnabled=false availableServices=[DATA] cellIdentity=CellIdentityLte:{ mCi=70817281 mPci=66 mTac=527 mEarfcn=1656 mBands=[] mBandwidth=2147483647 mMcc=204 mMnc=16 mAlphaLong=Simpel mAlphaShort=Simpel mAdditionalPlmns={} mCsgInfo=null} voiceSpecificInfo=null dataSpecificInfo=android.telephony.DataSpecificRegistrationInfo :{ maxDataCalls = 20 isDcNrRestricted = false isNrAvailable = false isEnDcAvailable = false LteVopsSupportInfo :  mVopsSupport = 3 mEmcBearerSupport = 2 } nrState=**** rRplmn=20416 isUsingCarrierAggregation=false}], mNrFrequencyRange=0, mOperatorAlphaLongRaw=Simpel, mOperatorAlphaShortRaw=Simpel, mIsDataRoamingFromRegistration=false, mIsIwlanPreferred=false} subId=1
[...snipping a lot more similar logging...]
```

What could be wrong?  Or at least, how can I further debug this?

Comment: Also cross-posted this to https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/android-12-cellbroadcastreceiver-permission-denial-causing-high-cpu-usage-in-com-android-phone-process.4529991/.

Comment: After more research, my current best quess is that the Qualcomm RIL driver (presumably via `qcrild`) very often sends a '1002 unsolicited response (voice) network state changed' event: com.android.phone logs "D RILJ    : Unsol response received; Sending ack to ril.cpp [PHONE0]:" and "D RILJ    : [UNSL]< UNSOL_RESPONSE_NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED [PHONE0]", often 10+ times per second.